# using execute in postgres returns syntax error

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, execute

I'm trying to debug this adn find out why I'm getting syntax error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myfunc(_report_id integer, _cutoff_date date)
 RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    _deliverable_id RECORD  ;
BEGIN
FOR _deliverable_id IN
      SELECT deliverable_id FROM public.deliverables where report_id=_report_id
   LOOP
      execute format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report.products_%I',_deliverable_id);
   END LOOP;
    
END
$function$
;
```

When I execute this, I get:

```
syntax error at or near ""(1111)""
```

1111 is one deliverable for sure, so this leads me to think it has something to do with the execute statement format, or the way I'm using %I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%I` is replaced as a whole identifier. If you want to concatenate things, you need to do it *before* replacement.

You can test/debug this for yourself by inspecting the result of the `format()` function:

```
select format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report.products_%I',42);
```

returns `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report.products_"42"`

you need to use:

```
select format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report.%I',concat('products_', 42));
```

which correctly returns  `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report.products_42`

(obviously you need to replace `42` with your variable.